# Efficient way to apply function to each row of data frame and return list of data frames

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a number of arguments and returns a data frame.  I also have a data frame where each row contains the arguments that I'd like to pass to my function, and I'd like to store the resulting set of data frames in a list.  What's an efficient way to do this? (I'm assuming it's some `apply` like method.)

For example, suppose you have the (meaningless) function

```
myfunc<-function(dfRow){
  return(data.frame(x=dfRow$x:dfRow$y,y=mean(dfRow$x,dfRow$y)))
}
```

and the data frame

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:3,y=4:6)
df
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

You can run

```
myfunc(df[1,])
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
4 4 1
```

but how would you run myfunc for each row of the data frame and store the results in a list?  I know how to do a basic for loop for this, but I'm looking for something that will run faster - something vectorized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "meaningless" function needs to have some meaning for `apply` to be able to work. For starters, you won't be able to use `$` since `apply` will see each row as a basic named vector.

Keeping that in mind, here's a re-write (along with a more *mean*ingful mean):

```
myfunc <- function(dfRow) {
  data.frame(x = dfRow[1]:dfRow[2], y = mean(c(dfRow[1], dfRow[2])))
}
```

or even:

```
myfunc <- function(dfRow) {
  data.frame(x = dfRow["x"]:dfRow["y"], y = mean(c(dfRow["x"], dfRow["y"])))
}
```

Here's what we get from `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (which is to apply the function by row):

```
apply(df, 1, myfunc)
# [[1]]
#   x   y
# 1 1 2.5
# 2 2 2.5
# 3 3 2.5
# 4 4 2.5
# 
# [[2]]
#   x   y
# 1 2 3.5
# 2 3 3.5
# 3 4 3.5
# 4 5 3.5
# 
# [[3]]
#   x   y
# 1 3 4.5
# 2 4 4.5
# 3 5 4.5
# 4 6 4.5
```

---

**Also**, don't always be too quick to write off `for` loops. `apply` is *optimized*, but basically hides a for loop somewhere in there.

Here are some speed comparisons:

```
## Function to use with `apply`
myfunc <- function(dfRow) {
  data.frame(x = dfRow["y"]:dfRow["x"], y = mean(c(dfRow["x"], dfRow["y"])))
}

## Function to use with `lapply`
myfunc1<-function(dfRow){
  return(data.frame(x=dfRow$x:dfRow$y,y=mean(dfRow$x,dfRow$y)))
}

## Sample data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(100, 100, TRUE),
                 y = sample(100, 100, TRUE))
```

Here are the functions to evaluate:

```
fun1 <- function() apply(df, 1, myfunc)

fun2a <- function() {
  listargs <- split(df,1:nrow(df))
}

fun3 <- function() {
  out <- vector("list", nrow(df))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    out[[i]] <- data.frame(x = df$x[i]:df$y[i], y = mean(c(df$x[i], df$y[i])))
  }
  out
}
```

And here are the results:

```
microbenchmark(fun2(), fun2(), fun3(), times = 20)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
#  fun1() 39.72704 39.99255 40.84243 43.77641  48.16284    20
#  fun2() 74.92324 79.20913 82.15130 83.12488 100.51695    20
#  fun3() 48.61772 49.59304 50.16654 56.17891  88.65290    20
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of answers, why not pass a list of arguments?  first split up your dataframe into a list, then `lapply` your function:

```
listargs <- split(df,1:nrow(df))

lapply(listargs,myfunc)

$`1`
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
4 4 1

$`2`
  x y
1 2 2
2 3 2
3 4 2
4 5 2

$`3`
  x y
1 3 3
2 4 3
3 5 3
4 6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use external package, then here's one using `data.table`:

Here's a version by simplifying your function:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
fA <- function(x, y) {
  data.frame(x = x:y, y = y:x)
}
dt = as.data.table(df)
result1 = dt[, list(ans = list(fA(x, y))), by=seq_len(nrow(dt))]
#    seq_len          ans
# 1:       1 <data.frame>
# 2:       2 <data.frame>
# 3:       3 <data.frame>
```

We create a `data.table` first, then aggregate `dt` on each row using `by=.` and on each row, we pass the corresponding `x` and `y` to `fA` function, and wrap the result in a `list`. Now just doing `result1$ans` gives the desired result.

If you insist on not passing individual objects, then you can do:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
fB <- function(dat) {
  data.frame(x = dat$x:dat$y, y = dat$y:dat$x)
}
dt = as.data.table(df)
result2 = dt[, list(ans = list(fB(.SD))), by=seq_len(nrow(dt))]
#    seq_len          ans
# 1:       1 <data.frame>
# 2:       2 <data.frame>
# 3:       3 <data.frame>
```

Here, we pass *Subset of Data*, `.SD` - a special variable, which carries the data that belongs to each group, to function `fB` instead. Once again doing `result2$ans` should get your answer.

HTH

Oh and BTW, it's okay to use spaces in your code; doesn't cost much :).